# How to: Read From colon(:)-Delimited Text Files in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I am building simple website in visual studio using C#.

I added simple new form item, tried to make "Sign Up" form as Facebook and other sites use for registration of new users.

I added a `DropDownList` into the form for inputting user country registration. I downloaded a world country list(.txt file) that is colon(:) delimited.

It looks like this:

```
AF:Afghanistan 
AL:Albania 
DZ:Algeria 
AS:American Samoa 
AD:Andorra 
AO:Angola
```

I want to read this file from program and add all country name into `DropDownList` as items.

How do I read the file and parse it by the colons?

Comment: The way this question is written its too broadly defined.  In order to get a good answer, I would suggest posting samples of the country list file as well as the code that you've tried and error's you've received.

Comment: AF:Afghanistan
AL:Albania
DZ:Algeria
AS:American Samoa
AD:Andorra
AO:Angola  This is the format of text saved in .txt format. I searched this in google saw they are using MyReader and delimiter was comma(,). I faced problem using this in C# and having : delimiter. please help, i am beginer

Comment: I have added your comments to your post, please fix it if i've misrepresented anything.

Comment: Also remember to mark as answer (the check mark under the votes) for the answer that helped you.  This helps future readers know how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file to a string and use `myString.Split(':')` to get an array of strings.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) to read the file.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
```

Once you have all the lines, loop through them and use the string split method as @overflowed has mentioned.  Or use LINQ

```
var list = lines.ToDictionary(c => c.Split(':')[0],c => c.Split(':')[1]);
```

Setting the country code to the value and the country to the text should be trivial if you put them in a dictionary and follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805610/2589202)

```
ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataBind();
```